# How to intent multiple way point in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-intent

[image]

Here is the code that the button link to google maps based on the textview address.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){
                    String address = textViewAddress.getText().toString();
                    String addressb = textViewAddressB.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+address));
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

How can I intent to multiple destinations/points in Google Maps? So If I created another textview address b, I want to show the location address a to address b to address c like the image above. Also possible intent to Waze as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this [API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-examples-using-waypoints).. by using `waypoints` you may add multiple destinations

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=18.519513,73.868315&destination=18.518496,73.879259&waypoints=18.520561,73.872435|18.519254,73.876614|18.52152,73.877327|18.52019,73.879935&travelmode=driving");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    try {
        Intent unrestrictedIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        startActivity(unrestrictedIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException innerEx) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a maps application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Update**
You can also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573404/map-intent-with-multiple-points)