# Google Map needs an API or not?

Tags: android, eclipse

If I need to lead someone to an address, I'll lead him through Google Maps .. so I code on applications some button link, when I click/thumb it, it will go to "Google map" to a coordinate 29.897717,31.203264 which aim at that place only, the question is, do I need an API for it?

Comment: yes you do if you plan on using google maps api v2 for android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need an api to navigate users.  You simply start an intent.

[Android Navigation intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459426/android-navigation-intent)

Comment: I don't? Thank you! I'll work with your link them :)